# Gwtp Autobean and rest

Tags: rest, gwt, autobean

I have InfraNameModel (Rest-type) to work with JSON

```
public interface IInfraNameBeanFactory extends AutoBeanFactory {
    IInfraNameBeanFactory INSTANCE = GWT.create(IInfraNameBeanFactory.class);
    AutoBean<InfraNameModel> infraName();
    AutoBean<InfraNameListModel> results();
}

public interface InfraNameListModel {
    List<InfraNameModel> getResults();
    void setResults(List<InfraNameModel> results);
}


public class InfraNameListModelImpl implements InfraNameListModel {
    private List<InfraNameModel> results;
    @Override
    public List<InfraNameModel> getResults() {
        return results;
    }
    @Override
    public void setResults(List<InfraNameModel> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}

public interface InfraNameModel {
    String getInfraName();
    void setInfraName(String infraName);
}

public class InfraNameModelImpl implements InfraNameModel {
    private String infraName;
    @Override
    public String getInfraName() {
        return infraName;
    }
    @Override
    public void setInfraName(String infraName) {
        this.infraName = infraName;
    }
}
```

I wanted to make them into a separate JAR
To make it common for the client and the server

But now I have errors

```
     [WARN] Class by.models.infraNameModel.InfraNameModel is used in Gin, but not available in GWT client code.
```

Is it real to pull such beans into a separate library?

Comment: If you have moved those classes to a shared package you need to add this package to a GWT module. This contains good examples for multi module project layout https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes

Comment: No, you misunderstood

The server is a standalone EJB application and as a GWT client it does not have any application

I want to do 1) GWT client 2) JavaEE server 3) REST libray
But I get an error